# Smooth transition using background images

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I am transitioning a couple of background images. However, I am noticing that when if the user acts before the transition has fully taken affect, the transition is instant.

For example, I hover over the div and the image takes 1 second to completely transition. However, I remove the cursor .5s into the transition. So it transitions back to the original image but instead of smoothly transitioning, it changes instantly. How do I make it smooth at all times?

```css
.class {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url("http://activite-paranormale.net/extended/photo/news/nature-harmony-girl.jpg"); 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease 0;
    transition: all 1s ease 0;
}
.class:hover {
    background-image:url("http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22700000/Spring-beautiful-nature-22727146-500-500.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="class"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/john84/pen/vEdPEW

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyk677ym/5/)

I changed `ease` to `ease-in-out` 
edit: Firefox doesn't support this, but there are many workarounds, example: 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyk677ym/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.class {
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    transition:all 500ms;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url("http://activite-paranormale.net/extended/photo/news/nature-harmony-girl.jpg"); 
}
.class2{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image:url("http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22700000/Spring-beautiful-nature-22727146-500-500.jpg");
}
.class:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: The `ease-in-out` trick doesn't work in Chrome 64 bit, Windows; but the two `<div>` trick works quite well.

Comment: @Passerby Make sure your mouse is on the image for 500ms.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP want. OP's transition needs to last 1s, and his/her problem is about half-way-out causing the transition to stop immediately.

Comment: @Passerby Then use a workaround, you should use one anyway because the current code what OP has doesn't support firefox.